# Обработка запросов Express.js с Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

Разрабатываю приложение на Vue (с помощью Vue CLI) и Express, за роутинг отвечает Vue Router. Для обработки HTTP запросов использую Express. При разработке vue cli работает на одном порте, а node js на другом. Как сделать так, чтобы после деплоя они работали вместе (например при загрузке на хостинг)?

Comment: сервер на одном хосте, приложение на другом

Comment: Если VDS, то запускаете 2 ноды и проксируете куда надо...

Comment: Вы про порт дев-сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Не имею опыта работы с vue, однако, вы можете попробовать следующее... Используйте npm-пакет https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy или директиву proxy_pass для nginx. Предположу, что express-приложение работает на 5000 порту, тогда следующий пример будет работать:

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var app = require('express')();
app.use('/proxy', proxy('localhost:5000'));
```

для express-http-proxy.

Или...

```
server {
    # server setup

    location /proxy {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

для nginx (proxy_pass),
после чего вы сможете из vue-приложения (на другом порту) отправлять http-запросы по адресу `/proxy/${your_route}`, где `${your_route}` - ваш целевой маршрут из express-приложения!